# css and js file path change when clicking other page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have working stylesheet in my codeigniter homepage but if i click on another page the file path also change. that's one reason why my stylsheet not working on other page

the filepath loke like this:

```
localhost/foldernam/controller_name/stylesheet.css
```

is there any way that if i visit on other page `filepath` be remain?
i just want the filepath should be like this

```
localhost/foldernam/stylesheet.css
```

in my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/systems/';
```

Answer (score 0):

add base_url variabel when you include stylesheet.css, for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url() . "stylesheet.css" ?>">
```

Add this code on header your html layout